# How do I pass the values of an Array through Android Intents?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

I did a good amount of searching, but I couldn't find consistent answers regarding transferring Array values, so I gave it a shot, but I failed

This is the Array I want to transfer

```
 public String[] usersAnswers1 = { "Test Array", //Array 0 };
```

This is the Activity that i'm trying to pass the intent from

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Test1.this, Results1.class);
 intent.putExtra("usersAnswers1", usersAnswers1);
 startActivity(intent);
```

I then try to catch it in the 2nd Activity, while trying to move it to the 3rd activity at the same time. This is because I need the Array values in Activity 3, and not Activity 2

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

Intent intent = new Intent(Results1.this, UsersAnswers1.class);
intent.putExtra("usersAnswers1", extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

then I catch it in the third activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String[] usersAnswers1i = extras.getStringArray("usersAnswers1");
```

And the moment my app reads the following line, I get a NullPointerException at this line

```
resultView1.setText("1. " + usersAnswers1i[0]);
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the  activity 2 ,you just need pass a copy.

intent.putExtras(extras)

will work.

you can see how it work by  the source code .

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO. Also, this answer does not provide more value than the others

Answer (score 1):

The problems is here:

`intent.putExtra("usersAnswers1", extras);`

`extras` is an instance of `Bundle` not of `String[]`. You are using the same key `usersAnswers1` for both the `String[]` and the `Bundle`

Comment: I replaced "extras" with "userAnswers1" as it was delcared in the first activity. But when I run my app, there is no test shown.

Comment: You just need to pass the `String[]` value through your 3rd `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

How about in the second activity you retrieve just the array and put it in the new intent extras using

```
String[] userAnswers = getExtras().getStringArray("usersAnswers1");
Intent intent = new Intent(Results1.this, UsersAnswers1.class);
intent.putExtra("usersAnswers1", usersAnswers);
```

then you would be able to retrieve it in the third activity.

Aside: create a constant for the key "userAnswers1".

Answer (score 0):

Change your second activity to

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(Results1.this, UsersAnswers1.class);
     intent.putExtra("usersAnswers1", extras.getStringArray("usersAnswers1")
    );
 startActivity(intent);
```

then  catch it in the third activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); String[] usersAnswers1i = extras.getStringArray("usersAnswers1");
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged in SO. Also, this answer does not provide more value than the others